# tftp server does not work behinf tap interface

Tags: tap, tftp

I have problem with tftp server that is running under qemu. Qemu is connected to host by tap interface. Output from wireshark shows that packed arrived to host, but hosts udp socket (and put command) ends up with timeut, netstat -au shows no data arrived.

Logs from wireshark:
[Wireshrk logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqZjt.png)

Tap interface is created like this:

```
tunctl -g 1000
ip addr add 192.168.7.1 broadcast 192.168.7.255 dev tap0
ip link set dev tap0 up
ip route add to 192.168.7.2 dev tap0
```

Iptabls and firewall are disabled. How can I start to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

It seem that is because in UDP packet my tftp server does not calculate CRC and put zeroes there. As I understand it is possible behaviur, so the question is why tap interface behave like that...